# generalize python script to run on all files in a directory

Tags: python

I have the following python script:

```
with open('ein.csv', 'r') as istr:
    with open('aus.csv', 'w') as ostr:
        for line in istr:
            line = line.rstrip('\n') + ',1'
            print(line, file=ostr)
```

how could this be generalized to run on all the files in a directory and output a seperate file for each one?

maybe have a function like this:

```
for phyle in list_files(.): 
    with open(phyle, 'r') as istr:
        with open('ausput_xyz.csv', 'w') as ostr:
            for line in istr:
                line = line.rstrip('\n') + ',1'
                print(line, file=ostr)

def list_files(path):
    # returns a list of names (with extension, without full path) of all files 
    # in folder path
    files = []
    for name in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, name)):
            files.append(name)
    return files
```

Comment: Which part of that are you stuck on, exactly?

Comment: I can ennumerate them like this: `os.listdir("somedirectory")` but I want to process them all with that short code component

Comment: So? What's the *problem*?

Comment: that I don't know how to do that

Comment: Are you trying to write them all to the same file, or have each file output to its own output file?

Comment: Do you know what a *"variable"* is?!

Comment: How would you construct the name of the output file given a generic name of the input file?

Comment: Can't you just use another for loop to iterate over the input files?

Comment: what about that edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the code in a function and call it:

```
def process(infilename):
    outfilename = os.path.splitext(infilename)[0] + "-out.csv" 
    with open(infilename, 'r') as istr:
        with open(outfilename, 'w') as ostr:
            for line in istr:
                line = line.rstrip('\n') + ',1'
                print(line, file=ostr)

def process_files(path):
    for name in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, name)):
            process(name)
```

In a directory with input files "abc.csv", "xyz.csv" this code will create output files named "abc-out.csv" and "xyz-out.csv".

Note that `os.listdir(path)` is called just once during the execution, so the list of files to process will not include the newly created output files.

Comment: that's awesome- especially about the call to `os.listdir`, but- I need to call those functions above or below to execute the code isn't it?

Comment: You need to call `process_files("/some/directory")` to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

First off, as a more pythonic way for dealing with `csv` files you better to use `csv` module and use `with` statement for opening the files which will close the file object automatically at the end of the block. And use `os.walk()` function to iterate over the files and directories of a specific path:

```
import csv
import os

for path_name, dirs, files in os.walk('relative_path'):
    for file_name in files:
        with open(file_name) as inp,open('{}.csv'.format(file_name),'wb') as out:
             spamwriter = csv.writer(out, delimiter=',')
             for line in inp:
                 spamwriter.writerow(line) # or line.split() with a specific delimiter
```

Note that if your script is not in a same path with your files directory you can add the path to the leading of your file name while you want to open them.

```
with open(path_name+'/'+file_name),...
```

Comment: @s.matthew.english Sorry a typo, it would be `writer` check it again.